# Flex 3 how to shrink the text

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

in flex 3 how to shrink the text when i shrink the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the font size style?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Label.html#style:fontSize

Comment: still i don't get a solution please brief me the solution.thanks in advance.

Comment: yourTextComponent.setStyle('fontSize',10);  or in mxml 

<mx:Text fontSize="10" />